# retrieve value from drop down bar and display result

Tags: php

on calculatePC.php, I have this code to display the finish_product

Select product:

```
<select class="itemTypes">
       <?php while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $row1['finish_product']; ?>">
           <?php echo $row1['finish_product']; ?>
           </option>
       <?php } ?></select>
    <br/><br/>
```

Let's say I have chosen Table as the finish_product.

On docalculate.php, I would like to display what I've chosen based on the dropdown list I've selected.

I tried this but there is error.

```
<?php echo $_POST['finish_product'] ?>
```

May I know how to display the result?

Comment: Edward  please up-vote the answer also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things:-

1. Create a form before select and give it an action
2. give name attribute to your select box, then only you can get data in `$_POST`

So do like below:-

```
<form method="POST" action = "docalculate.php"> // give the php file paht in action 
<select class="itemTypes" name="finish_product"> // give name attribute to your select box
       <?php while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $row1['finish_product']; ?>">
           <?php echo $row1['finish_product']; ?>
           </option>
       <?php } ?></select>
    <br/><br/>
<input type ="submit" name="submit" value ="Submit">
</form>
```

Now on `docalculate.php`:-

```
<?php
echo "<pre/>";print_r($_POST['finish_product']); // to see value comes or not
```

Note:- through Jquery its also possible. Thanks

Comment: hi, i have tried, however these code appears to have some error.
<?php echo "<pre/>";print_r($_POST['finish_product']);

Comment: You forgot to close it. 

<?php
echo "<pre/>";print_r($_POST['finish_product']); ?>

Comment: but in .php it is optional, I think

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exist:

```
$_POST['finish_product']
```

because you don't have a form element named "finish_product" in your markup.  Add that name to the form element:

```
<select name="finish_product" class="itemTypes">
```